# Redirecting old .html page to new without html extension page?

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've just changed permalinks in my wordpress site.

And my old links were like that,

```
http://www.sitename.com/category/postname.html
```

Now new links are

```
http://www.sitename.com/category/postname/
```

I'm getting 404 error at old links, how can i redirect all .html pages to new non .html pages  with .htaccess?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root, add these *before* your wordpress rules:

```
RedirectMatch 301  ^/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/
RedirectMatch 301  ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/$3/
```

Of if you need to limit it by hosts, you can use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sitename.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sitename.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/$3/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working right what about the subcategory pages sitename.com/category/subcategory/page.html to sitename.com/category/subcategory/page/

Comment: That's Great. Thank You Very Very Much. Which one is better for seo? to limit by host?

Comment: @JohnRock There's no difference. Limiting by host is only needed if you serve multiple hosts in the same document root. For example, you have a site `wordpress.site.com` and another `blog.blogsite.org` and both are hosted in the same document root directory, but you don't want the blog site to be affected, you'd use the `RewriteCond` to make the rules apply only to the first host.

Comment: Hi Jon. I can't get this to work for [https://george.doig.com.au/eulogy.html](https://george.doig.com.au/eulogy.html). I have the following in `.htaccess`: [http://pastebin.com/1R9KviY8](http://pastebin.com/1R9KviY8) - the site is subdomain multisite.

Comment: @JonLin this doesn't seem to work if I test on a subdomain.

Comment: I've just tried the first method on my WP site and it works great on the front end content (pages / blog posts) however it is preventing me from accessing /wp-admin and come up with 404 page not found.

Answer (score 1):

In the htaccess file, just put:

```
Redirect 301&nbsp; /postname.html&nbsp; http://www.sitename.com/category/postname/
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer (above) from `Jon Lin` caused some issues for me.
This is my result, which works well, and is a bit more compact.

It works for both, with and without directories in the path.

**Oneliner:**

```sh
RedirectMatch 301  ^/(.*)\.html$ /$1
```

Or if you need it limited by host:

```sh
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myDomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Example:
[image]