# .htaccess can't redirect non-Wordpress .html pages to Wordpress / pages

Tags: .htaccess

I've converted a Wolf CMS website @ `http://www.firstname.lastname.com.au` to a Wordpress MU subdomain site of `lastname.com.au`, @ `https://firstname.lastname.com.au`

The old website used `.html` URL extensions, and the new website does not.

I want to redirect `http://www.firstname.lastname.com.au/page.html` to `https://firstname.lastname.com.au/page` for all instances of `page`.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11926275/667903), I've tried the following in `.htaccess` without success:

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.firstname.lastname.com.au [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.firstname.lastname.com.au [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/$3/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} firstname.lastname.com.au [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} firstname.lastname.com.au [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/$3/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Help appreciated.

Regards,
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?firstname\.lastname\.com\.au [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ https://firstname.lastname.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Croises.