# Remove .html at the end and 301 redirect to the new link on subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have the following code, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926237/redirecting-old-html-page-to-new-without-html-extension-page) and adapted, that goes into .htaccess and redirects the browser to the new URL's without the `.html` extension at the end so:

```
website.com/about-us.html  -> website.com/about-us
```

which works great, but if I use the same code on a subdomain like `sub.website.com`, the homepage `sub.website.com` redirects to `sub.website.com/index`. The new page being made in php just removes the `.php` at the end and remains just `/index`

My code for doing this is:

```
RedirectMatch 301  ^/([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1/
RedirectMatch 301  ^/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/
RedirectMatch 301  ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/$3/
RedirectMatch 301  ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/$3/$4/
RedirectMatch 301  ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/
```

Comment: is there a 'about-us.html' on the subdomain? Or only a 'about-us.php'? It's a bit unclear: _"The new page being made in php just .."_

Comment: old page was made in html but now I recreated it in wordpress and /about-us.html became /about-us and I want to redirect whoever goes to /about-us.html to land on /about-us (same URL but without .html extension)

Comment: Open Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and visit  `sub.website.com` and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: redirects 301 `sub.website.com` to `sub.website.com/index` like I said in the post